# Laravel Find and Where querying

Tags: laravel, find, laravel-4, where-clause

Why does the following code return the exception "Call to a member function where() on a non-object"?

```
SomeModel::find( $id )->where('name', $name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

```
SomeModel::find( $id );
```

Returns a model, not a Query Builder instance, it's the end of the query.

You must do

```
SomeModel::where('name', $name)->where('somethingElse', '=', 'value')->first();
```

Comment: How would I achieve the same thing but to get model in return?
I need model, I want to use Eloquent to manipulate the data and save it afterwards.